# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Guid' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

With MVC EF code first, a new project can come with account functionality (login, register, etc).  I changed the DB connection string from pointing to the mdf file in the *App_Data* folder to have the connection string point to a **SQL Server instance**.  The *ASP.NET* specific tables were created in the **SQL Server Instance**.

Now when this following line of auto generated code runs:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,
    model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

It throws an exception:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Guid' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

The DB fields and domain model are Guids.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this error is telling you that EF materialized an Guid value from database, while in the required object type for this field is a string. I don't know what this line of code exactly does, but I suspect your POCO classes do not match the database schema or your model configuration is off.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my entity was using a Guid as an ID, but in the database the ID was nvarchar(300), I solved the problem by changing the **nvarchar(300)** to **uniqueidentifier**, but dont do this without knowing the effect that this could take on your database/application, in my case it was simple and that worked fine.

I hope this helps if someone else have the same problem.